# javascript jquery function is this somehow wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
function rebuildJSONObject(){
   $.getJSON('services.json', function(data) {
        //stof start
        var input = data;
        var output = { myservices: [] };
        for (var key in input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var i = 0, hostsinfo = input[key].hostsinfo; i < hostsinfo.length; i++) {
                    output.myservices.push({
                        'nametag': key,
                        'hostidn': hostsinfo[i]['hostidn'],
                        'details': hostsinfo[i]['details'],
                        'currstatus': hostsinfo[i]['currstatus'],
                        'currstatusclass': hostsinfo[i]['currstatusclass']
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        //stof end
        return output;
    });
}
//setting it for use later in the script
var serviceJSONObject = rebuildJSONObject();
```

I know the stuff going on in the function is working properly cause if I apply it to a click event it works charming. However I would rather load the JSON object into memory once and work with it client side there after unless saved. My Problem is however anywhere I call "serviceJSONObject" I get an "undefined" error.

So How am I doing this wrong and how would I define a variable like this early in the game so the rest of the script can use said variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a cache property to a function that will store the result of the initial output (loaded via ajax) and returning the saved state to any consecutive call.

```
function rebuildJSONObject(callback) {
    var self = this;

    if (typeof self.cache !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(self.cache);
        }
        return;
    }

    $.getJSON('services.json', function(data) {
        //stof start
        var input = data,
            output = { myservices: [] };

        for (var key in input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var i = 0, hostsinfo = input[key].hostsinfo; i < hostsinfo.length; i++) {
                    output.myservices.push({
                        'nametag': key,
                        'hostidn': hostsinfo[i]['hostidn'],
                        'details': hostsinfo[i]['details'],
                        'currstatus': hostsinfo[i]['currstatus'],
                        'currstatusclass': hostsinfo[i]['currstatusclass']
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        //stof end
        self.cache = output;

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(self.cache);
        }

        return;
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** For the first time you will need to call this function asynchronously and supply a callback function, for example

```
rebuildJSONObject(function(output) {

    /*
     * Process your output here
     */

    console.log(output);

});
```

Each consecutive time you can again use it synchronously:

```
console.log(rebuildJSONObject.cache);
```

Comment: An ajax call is not synchronized so rebuildJSONObject doesn't return a thing.

Comment: how would I access the equivocation of serviceJSONObject then? For example I have a button click event that I check the length of the object/variable to ensure theres something there.. now without actually defining it as a variable would I call it like rebuildJSONObject().length ?

Comment: @PoweRoy if its not yielding a result, or its not going to give me one per say. How would I get a variable via any form of AJAX transaction that I can store client side? to work with. That last longer then the duration of the function?

Comment: That's why it's normally better to work with the variable inside the callback. If you want it to be available elsewhere however you have no choice but to put it into a variable with higher scope (i.e. global)

Comment: Store it in a variable outside the function, or pass it by function variable (see Smirkins answer)

Comment: I still have some playing around to do with this, but this one seems to be my closest working rendition. Appreciate the help everyone

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `output` is returned before the callback function is called. You should be able to save the value to `serviceJSONObject` by using a closure:

```
function rebuildJSONObject(serviceJSONObject){
   $.getJSON('services.json', function(data) {
        //stof start
        var input = data;

        // Use the serviceJSONObject that is passed into rebuildJSONObject
        serviceJSONObject = { myservices: [] };
        for (var key in input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var i = 0, hostsinfo = input[key].hostsinfo; i < hostsinfo.length; i++) {
                    serviceJSONObject.myservices.push({
                        'nametag': key,
                        'hostidn': hostsinfo[i]['hostidn'],
                        'details': hostsinfo[i]['details'],
                        'currstatus': hostsinfo[i]['currstatus'],
                        'currstatusclass': hostsinfo[i]['currstatusclass']
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        //stof end
    });
}
//setting it for use later in the script
var serviceJSONObject;
rebuildJSONObject(serviceJSONObject);
```

Comment: I believe this will still have the problem that there is nothing to prevent serviceJSONObject being accessed before the JSON call has returned. It will still be undefined if accessed before the ajax call comes back.

Comment: @njreed.myopenid.com is right, the code that follows `rebuildJSONObject(serviceJSONObject);` might need the `serviceJSONObject` variable sooner than `rebuildJSONObject` will return.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with this.

1. The call to getJSON is asynchronous so you need to be careful you don't try to use the results before the call has returned your results.
2. The way it is at the moment, the results will not be returned to `serviceJSONObject`. The `return output` statement is setting the return for the anonymous function, not the return value for `rebuildJSONObject`, so the results will just disappear. If you want the results to be available elsewhwere in code you will either need to store them in a global variable or access them inside the callback.